# How to delete a data from MySQL table after each 15 minute?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table call onlinenow. on this table contain **onlineId(INT), onlineIP(INT) and onlineDateTime(TimeStamp)**. This table get insert every time client visit the site and onlineDateTime get update every page refresh.

So the problem is how to delete a data from table onlinenow when onlineDateTime + 15 minute example:

I visit the site at 08:00 and close my browser so the onlineDateTime will not get update anymore and after 08:15 delete the data

Here my code that handle insert and update table onlinenow :

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$errMsg = '';
if(empty($errMsg)) {
    try {   
            $check = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM onlinenow WHERE onlineIP = '$ip'");
            $check->execute();
            $dataonline = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($dataonline == true) {
                $stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE onlinenow SET onlineDateTime = '$naw' WHERE onlineIP = '$ip'");
                $stmt->execute();
            }else{
                $stmt = $connect->prepare('INSERT INTO onlinenow (onlineIP, onlineDateTime) VALUES (:onlineIP, :onlineDateTime)');
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':onlineIP' => $ip,
                    ':onlineDateTime' => $naw
                    ));
            }

        }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
            $errMsg = $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

What I have to do to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Use cron job to schedule a task.

Comment: beside cron job is that posible to make a code that can handle this problem ?

Comment: for what purpose you need to take the result of online users?

Comment: for information how people online on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a file in which you will add functionality to delete a record.

Then, add that file in your cpanel -> cron jobs -> set time to run after every 15 min

You can add your email at that interface so after every 15 min cron job executed, record deleted and an email will be sent at your email.

Comment: how do i use this cron job on my hosting there no cronjob menu.

Comment: Definitely it will be having. You can search `cron`. By the way, which hosting you are using ?

Comment: i use cloudways

Comment: Maybe, this will be helpful : https://support.cloudways.com/scheduling-cron-job-from-console/

Comment: owh i see now the cron will do the delete automatically right ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a cron scheduler that will run every 15mins. Here is an example of it.

`*/15 * * * *` -- this means, it will run every 15mins

`*/15 * * * * /path/to/php deleteRecords.php`

Below is deleteRecords.php:

```
<?php

mysql_query("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITIONS");

?>
```

Comment: owh so what this cron do it will triger a file that i make ever x minute i setting it ?

Comment: This cron will execute the PHP file every 15mins. You can have your code/logic in this PHP file that should get executed every 15mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like this

> DELETE FROM  onlineNow WHERE ADDDATE(onlineDateTime,INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) <= NOW();

This query you have to run in cron jobs at every 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

```
When client visit your site and client login in to your site at time you insert onlineIP,and onlineDateTime on table "onlinenow" and also update onlinedateTime every page refresh.
```

You need update onlineDateTime when user closed browser directly.
Solution : Need to set cron jobs

Write your delete code in offline.php set this file name with your file fullpath in your cron jobs cpanel -> cron jobs ->serverpath.offline.php
You can call this cron job every 15 minute so you can need to set cron job execution time 15 minute

```
**delete record onlinedateTime is greater than 15 minute**
```

offline.php

$query="DELETE FROM onlinenow WHERE onlinedateTime < (NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)";
    mysqli_query($query);